# Bitwise vs shift (Python)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

What is the fastest operation between

```
0b11111111 >> 1 << 1
```

and

```
0b11111111 & 0b11111110
```

?

Thank you !

Comment: Use a profiler and measure the time yourself!

Comment: Why tagged with: [tag:c] ?

Comment: You should not care about it until it becomes a bottleneck. And when it does become the bottleneck, you will know that because you will have measured the performance. Then you will have no need to ask ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the results of [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

```
mquadri$ python -m "timeit" "0b11111111 >> 1 << 1"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0159 usec per loop
mquadri$ python -m "timeit" "0b11111111 & 0b11111110"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0162 usec per loop
```

Execution time for both is almost same with `0b11111111 >> 1 << 1` faster than `0b11111111 & 0b11111110` by *0.0003* usec (negligble). (*Note: this time may vary based on the system configuration*).

But I'll *personally suggest* to go with `0b11111111 & 0b11111110` as it looks cleaner.